# Can multiple CSS hover popups occupy the same space within a single div?

Tags: css, popup, modalpopups

I'm trying to have text spans pop up on a hover pseudo-class for different lines in a menu (list items).  I can have the pop-ups occupy the same space in the div if the menu/list is horizontal, but a vertical list places the popups at the same vertical height as the "parent" list/menu item.

Here is the relevant code I have so far:

```
<div id="greenback">
  <div class="serviceframe">
    <div class="serviceslist">
<ul>
<li><a href="">item 1<span>this is popup1.</span></a></li>

<p><li><a href="">item 2<span>This is popup 2's text but I want it to appear in exactly the same place as popup 1's text does.</span></a></li></p>

<p><li><a href="">item 3<span>same here - how can I get all popups positioned in exactly the same place?</span></a></li></p>
</ul>
        </div><!-- closes serviceslist-->
    </div><!-- closes serviceframe -->
</div><!-- closes greenback-->
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: disc url(w-arrow.png) outside;
    }



#greenback {
    position: relative ;
        top: 0em ;
    width: 800px ;
    height: 250px ;
    background-color: #7EBB11 ;
    border: 3px solid #112D82 ;
    }

/*********SERVICE LIST MENU**********/
.serviceframe { 
    position: relative ;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 94% ; 
    background-color: #666666 ; 
    top: 3%; bottom: 3%;
    }
/*--serviceframe is now sitting in greenback--*/

.serviceslist {
    position: relative ;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 90%  ;
    top: 1% ;
    background-color: #7EBB11 ;
    font-family: Optima, Calibri, Candara, Century-Gothic, 
    Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100% ;
    color: black ;
    display: table-cell ;
    vertical-align: middle ;
    z-index: 100 ;
}

.serviceslist a 
    {position: relative;
    display: table-cell; text-align: left; height: 100%;  font: 1em sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none; color: #112D82; 
    background: #7EBB11 ; 
}

/*appearance of the <a> item (but before the <span> tag) on hover*/
.serviceslist a:hover {
    color: white;
    }

/*appearance of the spanned content within <a></a> tags when not hovered*/
.serviceslist a span {display: none;}

/*appearance of spanned content within <a> tags when hovered*/
.serviceslist a:hover span {
    position: absolute;
    display: table-cell;  
    margin-top: 0em; margin-left: -50%; z-index: 100;
    width: 40%; height: auto; color: #FFFFFF;  background-color: #7EBB11;
    font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif; text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please reformat the code?  It's hard to read as it is (indent each codeline four spaces to make it easy to read on stackoverflow).

Comment: I've edited the formatting for him/her

Comment: Lol, we all edit the formating for him... :D

Comment: thank you - first time user issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My my, that's a whole lot of HTML and css for a simple task.  I wont try to read through it all, but just give you your answer

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item 1<span>this is popup1.</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 2<span>This is popup 2's text but I want it to appear in exactly the same place as popup 1's text does.</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 3<span>same here - how can I get all popups positioned in exactly the same place?</span></a></li>
</ul>

ul { position: relative; }
ul span { position: absolute; }
```

You only need to have position relative on the ul (or one of the divs above it) because that's what you're wanting to make your spans absolute to.

Also, kill those P tags around your LIs. You shouldn't have anything between the UL and LI.

Comment: thanks, it didn't seem to make any difference (at least in FF) but I'll try it in others. the P tags were just to give me some pacing and din't affect the result either way but I've taken them out anyway.  cheers patrick.

Comment: @patrick - I striped a lot of css out of that to keep it simple, but having position relative and absolute in those places with top/left declarations would most certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all the different spans to be appeared in the same place?
You set the relative position in A, which make the span appear "relative" to it.

Fix:

- Remove relative positioning in
      anchor. // Though, it doesn't seem to matter in
      FF for some reason
- Set positioning(top, left, etc.) for
  span to desired value.

*Your code snippet doesn't work on IE6/7 so I didn't bother the bugs in it.

Comment: thanks so much, making the a:hover condition the one that defines the position works a treat. So logical...this is my first ever CSS so I'm learning as I go. I want to get it right in FF/Sf 1st & then fix for IE (so I can achieve one thing that works first!) - a good approach or no? cheers Patrick.

Comment: It's a usual approach, since IE6 is so quirky.
I believe the use of percent in height, make your snippet buggy in IE.